# SQL Query is returning NULL for the inner join fields

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sindidaskalies.sindidaskalia_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS sindidaskalia_names, classes.name AS class_name, classes.*, users.*, teachers.name as teacher_name 
FROM users 
    INNER JOIN classes ON classes.id = users.class_id 
    INNER JOIN teachers ON teachers.id = classes.ipefthinos OR classes.voithos = teachers.id 
    INNER JOIN sindidaskalies ON sindidaskalies.user_id = users.id
WHERE users.id = ?
```

This is my query code ^

```
{
   "sindidaskalia_names": null,
   "class_name": null,
   "id": 4475,
   "name": "Marios",
   "voithos": null,
   "ipefthinos": null,
   "sex": "Male",
   "class_id": 1,
   "password": "$2b$12$Hwr3n72Swd4vwX/bMxwGGu9XbaZoShxCmCxLF8vaaDBEB4quQfzvu",
   "surname": "Kyriacou",
   "teams_mail": "email",
   "teacher_name": null
}
```

Output ^
If I request the data one by one without the inner join then I get them just fine but when I try to use it, then it's just NULL. Below are pictures of the tables I have

[image: Users table]

[image: Sindidaskalies table]

[image: Idikotites table]

[image: Classes table]

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue with sample data in a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3aMmxpPT)?

Comment: @forpas - Here you go: https://dbfiddle.uk/5wwbwkq5

Comment: In your sample data: there is only 1 row in the table `teachers` with `id=22235` and only 1 row in the table `classes` with values for `voithos=1` and `ipefthinos=2`. The join is `INNER JOIN teachers ON teachers.id = classes.ipefthinos OR classes.voithos = teachers.id` which never succeeds.

Comment: Correct @forpas, if you try with `INNER JOIN teachers ON teachers.id = classes.ipefthinos OR classes.voithos = teachers.idikotita_id`You will get result

Answer (score 0):

You have the problem with your teacher table, maybe instead of using **teachers.id** you need to use **teachers.idikotita_id**

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sindidaskalies.sindidaskalia_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS sindidaskalia_names, 
       classes.name AS class_name, classes.*, users.*, 
       teachers.name as teacher_name 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN classes ON classes.id = users.class_id 
INNER JOIN teachers ON teachers.idikotita_id = classes.ipefthinos OR classes.voithos = teachers.idikotita_id 
INNER JOIN sindidaskalies ON sindidaskalies.user_id = users.id 
WHERE users.id = 4475;
```